# Have a case when deposit the same value if certain criteria are met

Tags: sql, postgresql

In Redshift SQL ––

I want to make a case like

```
 case when first_name ilike 'p%' 
      then (the cell's value) 
      else null 
 end as p_names
```

so if we have a column:

```
|  name  |
+--------+
| patty  |
| bryan  |
| peter  |
```

the result would be

```
| p_name |
+--------+
| patty  |
| (null) |
| peter  |
```

so that basically if the case is met it just pulls in the original cell's value on a per-cell level. Is this possible?

Comment: What is a "cell"?

Comment: One more row in the result than in the table?

Comment: @jarlh: it looks like the first row is the column header actually.

Comment: @GMB, guess you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select case when col1 like 'p%' 
            then col1 
            else null 
       end p_names
from test
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=98caae8b1746603127ca69ed9384e4c5)

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your expression looks fine, and can be simplified a little: without an `else`, `case` returns `null` if no `when` condition is fulfilled - so you can just skip that part:

```
case when first_name ilike 'p%' then first_name end as p_names
```